# Adding common methods to MongoRepositories

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to add a set of common methods to all MongoRepositories in my project without any success thus far.

I have tried to approach this problem by adding a custom MongoRepositoryFactoryBean but I can't get this to work. Here is the complete code of my very basic test project:

(I've also dumped the project on GitHub over at https://github.com/tentelemed/mongo-demo)

DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
@Document(collection = "clients")
public class Client {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Client(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getters & Setters 
}
```

BaseRepository.java

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> {

    Page<T> mySearch(Query query, Pageable pageable);
}
```

BaseRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID>
        implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {

    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
    private MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> mySearch(Query query, Pageable pageable) {

        long total = mongoOperations.count(query, metadata.getJavaType() );
        return new PageImpl<T>(mongoOperations.find(query.with(pageable), metadata.getJavaType()), pageable, total);
    }
}
```

ClientsRepository.java

```
public interface ClientsRepository extends MongoRepository<Client, String>, BaseRepository<Client, String> {

}
```

BaseRepositoryFactoryBean.java

```
public class BaseRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends MongoRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
        extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    public BaseRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends R> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport getFactoryInstance(MongoOperations operations) {

        return new BaseRepositoryFactory<T,I>(operations);
    }

    private static class BaseRepositoryFactory<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepositoryFactory {

        private MongoOperations mongo;

        public BaseRepositoryFactory(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
            super(mongoOperations);

            this.mongo = mongoOperations;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            TypeInformation<T> information =  ClassTypeInformation.from((Class<T>)metadata.getDomainType());
            MongoPersistentEntity<T> pe = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity<T>(information);
            MongoEntityInformation<T,ID> mongometa = new MappingMongoEntityInformation<T, ID>(pe);

            return new BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID>( mongometa,  mongo);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return BaseRepository.class;
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces the following exception upon launch :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller' defined in file [/Users/anthony/Documents/SORT/code-zipped/tutorials-master/demo/target/classes/com/example/demo/Controller.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface com.example.demo.BaseRepository to match the given arguments: [class org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MappingMongoEntityInformation, class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface com.example.demo.BaseRepository to match the given arguments: [class org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MappingMongoEntityInformation, class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface com.example.demo.BaseRepository to match the given arguments: [class org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MappingMongoEntityInformation, class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$4(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:514) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:514) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:125) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html#repositoryBaseClass--, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository

Comment: @JB_Nizet D'OH! That'll work too. Thanks!